# strcat and malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc

Currently, I need to strcat() 2 strings together. The catch is that I have to do this 3 times. (Total of 6 concatenations). 
The procedure is this, repeated 3 times using loops:

1. Malloc a string
2. Using for loop, call strcat 2 times
3. Free the string

The problem is that even after I free the string and re-malloc, the strcat seems to keep on concatenating the previous string.

For example:

**Expected Output from AA BB CC DD EE FF**

- strcat string 1: AABB
- strcat string 2: CCDD
- strcat string 3: EEFF

**Actual Output:**

- strcat string 1: AABB
- strcat string 2: AABBCCDD
- strcat string 3: AABBCCDDEEFF

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

```
void sendInitialHand(card * deck) {

    char * stringToSend;
    playerNode * curNode;
    curNode = housePlayers.head;

    for (int i=0; i<housePlayers.playerCount; i++) {

        stringToSend = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);

        for (int j=0; j<52; j++) {
            if (deck[j].inPlay == curNode->playerFD) {
                strcat(stringToSend, deck[j].identifier);
            }
        }

        for (int j=0; j<52; j++) {
            if (deck[j].inPlay == 10) {
                strcat(stringToSend, deck[j].identifier);
            }
        }    

        printf("[NETWORK] Send %d the following: %s\n", curNode->playerFD, stringToSend);
        //send(curNode->playerFD, stringToSend, 6, 0);
        free(stringToSend);
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see some code snippets ?

Comment: show us the actual code otherwise we can't find the error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `ptr=malloc(…)`, before `strcat()`, initialize the space with `*ptr = '\0';`.  The memory returned by `malloc()` is usually not zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your looping structure using printf statements, it's likely that you aren't freeing what you think are when you think you are. Will edit answer based on code..

You only re-malloc, which just says hey I'm going to write here.. which is what you already said. Try to free/re-initialize the variable

Comment: This 'answer' should probably have been a comment.  The code arrived a couple of minutes after you posted this.  Since its material isn't directly germane to the problem, I suggest it should be deleted (but I'd rather not down-vote to force your hand).